# Updating NSMutableArray from sectioned tableview after item is deleted

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a tableview which is sectioned alphabetically. I have an `NSMutableArray *drinks` which is my original datasource which its being populated with `NSMutableDictionary's` from a plist. in my `viewDidLoad` method. I then iterate through my array and create the keys for the sections and the number of rows in each section in my `viewWillAppear` method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    BOOL found;

    // Loop through the whiskys and create our keys
    for (NSMutableDictionary *whisky in self.drinks)
    {
        NSString *c = [[whisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] substringToIndex:1];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:c])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
    }
    // Loop again and sort the whiskys into their respective keys
    for (NSDictionary *whisky in self.drinks)
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:[[whisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:whisky];
    }
    // Sort each section array
    for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NAME_KEY ascending:YES]]];
    }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view

    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchPaths lastObject];
    NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScotchList.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:writeableDBPath];

    self.drinks = tmpArray;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

    //Register for application exiting information so we can save data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

}
```

All of this works fine and dandy. Then when I delete a row it works fine as well. How ever when I go to a new view it and come back to the tableview the deleted row reappears. So I need to update my original datasource (drinks) because everytime the viewAppears it pulls from the original datasource again. So I tried to get the item (whisky) at the row and remove it from the array. But it throws a sigabrt. This is my delete row method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //DELETE THE ROW FROM THE DATA SOURCE
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSDictionary *whisky = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.drinks removeObject:whisky];

        if ([[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] count] > 0)
        {
            // Section is not yet empty, so delete only the current row.
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }
        else
        {
            // Section is now completely empty, so delete the entire section.
            [self.sections removeObjectForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

this is what the log shows:

```
2012-07-06 15:36:42.454 WhiskyBook[3275:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x3998a17b 0x3494395b 0x398d83bd 0x3e6b5 0x32a0cd11 0x328f0d09 0x328f0cbb 0x328f0c95 0x328f09eb 0x328f1369 0x328ef791 0x328dd72d 0x328dd009 0x339a7603 0x339a7233 0x3995a873 0x3995a817 0x39959611 0x398d6be5 0x398d6a71 0x339a634b 0x329037f5 0x3ac09 0x33cc7b20)

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

(lldb)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line is this called on? You can probably solve this by outputting the arrays you're looking at and seeing which one is nil.

Comment: Also it looks like you're trying to change an immutable array - that's why your error has __NSArrayI in it (the I stands for immutable)

Comment: The issue comes when i put in the 'NSDictionary *whisky' inside the 'tableview commitEditingStyle' method. When I output whisky to the log it shows the item (whisky) the way it should.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. Instead of trying to remove the object from the original datasource inside of the commitEditingStyle method I just made an NSDictionary property for my master-viewController alloc'd and inited it in my viewDidLoad then assigned it the item that I want to be deleted inside of the commitEditingStyle method. Then inside of my viewWillDisappear method I removed it from the original datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Instead of trying to remove the object from the original datasource inside of the commitEditingStyle method I just made an NSDictionary property for my master-viewController alloc'd and inited it in my viewDidLoad then assigned it the item that I want to be deleted inside of the commitEditingStyle method. Then inside of my viewWillDisappear method I removed it from the original datasource.